# Discord vs bot 13 not able to assign roles giving error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'guild')

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am using discord js v13.6. I have written in my code where after using a slash command user is assigned many roles which are stored in a array named rolenumber. The problem is I am getting this error every time

```
 await client.users.fetch(memberId).then((user,interaction) => {
            user.send("Give me a few moments while I verify your details");
            (async function(user){

            
            let RoleArray = rolenumber.split(","); 
            //let guild = client.guilds.cache.get(guildNumber);
            //let member = await client.users.fetch(msg);   
            
            for(let num of RoleArray) {
                //console.log("Roles Inside a for loop",num);
                let role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get(num);
                let data = await user.roles.add(role).catch(console.error);
                //user.roles.add(num).catch(console.error);            
            }   
            
           
            let welcomeMessage = 'Welcome <@'+ user.id +'>, you are now officially part of channel.';
            const channelMessage = await client.channels.cache.get(channelNumber);
            channelMessage.send(welcomeMessage);
        })();
```

here the guildNumber is a guild Number which is hidden for security reason from the question.  I am getting this as error message:

> ```
> let role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get(num);
>                                        ^
>
> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'guild')
>
> at E:\OutscalGit\DiscordBot\index.js:200:44
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**interaction** is undefined
Are you sure, interaction is passed to here?

you can use it but it not perfect

`let role = interaction?.guild?.roles?.cache?.get(num);`

Comment: interaction is passed throughout the functions so yes it is defined. will try and let you know. thanks for your time.

Comment: Did not worked now getting another error in the next line. So you are correct that interaction even after being passed is undefined. Thanks for putting me in this line. Will now try to resolve it as well. If you have solution you can suggest that as well or edit your answer here so I can mark it as correct. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`Promise.prototype.then`'s fulfillment callback only takes 1 argument.

```js
await client.users.fetch(memberId).then((user) => {
            user.send("Give me a few moments while I verify your details")
            // ...
})
```

Assuming `interaction` is already defined above, it should work

Comment: Thank you for your time on the problem. It is resolved. The issue was that interaction was not defined. Thanks

Comment: @COdeingNinja yes, this is why it was undefined